# URI encodes control signs into absolute path

Tags: c#, encoding, uri

We are sending data to an API with several endpoints. For this we put the base URL into a variable and appending the route info to it. But the request cannot be resolved to a service, as the URI-object is putting not printable characters into the path.
The code for create the URI object:

```
var uri = new Uri(_url + "/api/v1/create");
```

The result is:

```
https://localhost%E2%80%8B/api%E2%80%8B/v1%E2%80%8B/create
```

We are using .Net Framework 4.7.2.
Does anyone know, whats happening?

Comment: Did you copy/paste that `"/api/v1/create"` string into your question, or re-type it into your question?

Comment: I retyped it, but it does not make any difference. I already retyped the URL in the code file and even tried a hard coded path.

Comment: The `%E2%80%8B` is a [zero-width space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) -- I suspect it's present in your original string, and isn't being introduced by `Uri`

Comment: We went for a nuclear option and retyped all calls. I don't know how the symbol survived the retyping, but you guys helped us a lot for pinning the error.

Comment: The `diff` functionality of your version control system should be able to tell you which one changed

Answer (score 0):

As canton7 pointed out, the problem had been the zero-length space [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63054002/uri-encodes-control-signs-into-absolute-path#comment111502466_63054002)
We retyped the whole method calls - not only the URLs - and now the system is running. Thanks.